# Convert UnixTimeStamp to NSDate with Day light saving time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a GMT timestamp "1273051632" where GMT offset is  -5.I want to convert this into local time with day light saving time in my iPhone application. Converting it using NSdateFormatter gives me

> 1273051632 translates to Wednesday, May 5th 2010, 04:27:12 (GMT -5)

This is not adding day light saving time...

> (The correct result  should be Wednesday, May 5th 2010, 05:27:12 (GMT -5)) , right ?

Please help me how to convert above Unixtimestamp to NSString accounting day light saving time .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds]`